# More complex extending generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have two trees of classes with generics and I cannot figure out one thing, that I know how to solve in Java with `<? extends ...>`.

First AI tree:

```
abstract class AbstractAI<TCtrl> : MonoBehaviour where TCtrl: IRotableWeaponController

abstract class AbstractShipAI : AbstractAI<IShipController>

class ModularAI : AbstractShipAI

Some other classes that extend AbstractAI and use various modules
```

Modules tree:

```
abstract class AbstractModule<TAi, TCtrl> : AIModule where TAi: AbstractAI<TCtrl> where TCtrl: IRotableWeaponController
{
    public virtual void Init(TAi parent)
}

class ShootModule: AbstractModule<AbstractAI<IRotableWeaponController>, IRotableWeaponController>

Some other modules that extend AbstractModule and can be used only with some AIs, that have required capabilities
```

Used controller interfaces tree:

```
interface IRotableWeaponController

interface IShipController: IRotableWeaponController

Other interfaces extending IRotableWeaponController...
```

The issue is:

```
class ModularAI : AbstractShipAI
{
    public ShootModule shootModule;

    protected override void Start()
    {
        shootModule.Init(this); // Error: Argument type 'ModularAI' is not assignable to parameter type 'AbstractAI<IRotableWeaponController>'    
    }
}
```

`ModularAI` is `AbstractAI<IShipController>`, `IShipController` is `IRotableWeaponController`, but I get an error.

In Java I would do:

```
abstract class AbstractModule<TAi, TCtrl> : AIModule where TAi: AbstractAI<? extends TCtrl> where TCtrl: IRotableWeaponController
```

I know it's kind of complex and there is probably a better way to design it (and I may eventually get to it one day) but I want to know, how to solve this issue.
Please, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) by inserting an interface in place of the abstract class, appropriately marked for it:

```
interface IAbstractAI<out TCtrl> where TCtrl : IRotableWeaponController {
}

abstract class AbstractAI<TCtrl> : MonoBehaviour, IAbstractAI<TCtrl> where TCtrl : IRotableWeaponController {
}

abstract class AbstractModule<TAi, TCtrl> : AIModule where TAi : IAbstractAI<TCtrl> where TCtrl : IRotableWeaponController {
    public virtual void Init(TAi parent) {
    }
}

class ShootModule : AbstractModule<IAbstractAI<IRotableWeaponController>, IRotableWeaponController> {
}

class ModularAI : AbstractShipAI {
    public ShootModule shootModule;

    protected override void Start() {
        shootModule.Init(this); // Error: Argument type 'ModularAI' is not assignable to parameter type 'AbstractAI<IRotableWeaponController>'    
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I'm still new to C# and I'm mostly using it in Java style, this is new to me :)

Answer (score 3):

I made an easier example to illustrate your issue :

```
class Fruit { }
class Apple : Fruit { }
class FruitMaker<T> where T : Fruit { }

class Program
{
    static void HandleFruit(FruitMaker<Fruit> fruitMaker) { }

    static void Main()
    {
        FruitMaker<Apple> appelMaker = new FruitMaker<Apple>();
        FruitMaker<Fruit> fruitMaker = appelMaker; //cannot convert from 'FruitMaker<Apple>' to 'FruitMaker<Fruit>'
        HandleFruit(fruitMaker);

    }
}
```

What you need is generics covariance, you need to pass `FruitMaker<Apple>` to a method that expects `FruitMaker<Fruit>`.
This is enabled with the `out` keyword, what you want is `class FruitMaker<out T> where T : Fruit { }`, but you can't do that because `FruitMaker` is not an interface. You can solve this as follows :

```
class Fruit { }
class Apple : Fruit { }
interface IFruitMaker<out T> where T : Fruit { }
class FruitMaker<T> : IFruitMaker<T> where T : Fruit { }

class Program
{
    static void HandleFruit(IFruitMaker<Fruit> fruitMaker) { }

    static void Main()
    {
        FruitMaker<Apple> appelMaker = new FruitMaker<Apple>();
        IFruitMaker<Fruit> fruitMaker = appelMaker; //this is allowed thanks to the out keyword
        HandleFruit(fruitMaker);

    }
}
```

Notice that I introduced an interface just to be able to add the `out` keywork.